# Error While Compiling C program in Linux Mint

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, ld

i am getting errors while compiling a simple C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
      int i=5;
printf("I value is %d",i);
}
```

The Errors are ..

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my gcc version is..

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Can anyone know what my problem is ?

Comment: Well, that's a linker error, not a compiler error.  What does adding the `-v` flag output?  Besides that, `main` should return `int` and as a result needs a `return` statement.

Comment: Program told You what's your problem already. Have You updated your OS recently?

Comment: -@CarlNorum 
That's okay. But, i'm getting the same error.. after adding the return statement and changing void to int.

Comment: @pivovarit yes dude. You r rite. i updated my OS. any suggestions ??

Comment: sort of unrelated, but void main is invalid for hosted implementations if you are a "by the book" sort of C programmer.

Comment: thank you all for your immediate response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sometimes occurs if you're running a back-level of `binutils`. You need to, as a first step, check the dependencies for your `gcc` version and ensure they're all installed.

Comment: just before doing this, i installed binutils. Is that affect to this ?? @paxdiablo

Comment: @Siva, almost certainly. You've now probably got an incompatibility between gcc and binutils which you'll need to fix.

Comment: can u please tell me the way to fix them -@paxdiablo

Comment: @Siva, probably the easiest way is to look into `aptitude reinstall` provided Ubuntu hasn't deviated too much from its Debian roots. I assumed that since you had installed binutils, you knew what you were doing, though I may have been mistaken :-) It's not a painless process though, you may want to ask a question over at http://askubuntu.com/ since it's not really programming-related any more.

Comment: hmmm i installed binutils manually by downloading the package and ./configure, make and make install. 

any wayzz thank you for your help. Actually i faced this error while installing the "texinfo-5.1". @paxdiablo

Comment: If `binutils` was updated, consider updating `gcc`.  Make sure that gcc is configured to pick up the newly installed version of binutils.

Answer (score 2):

Following the tutorial below, the suggested to insert the path /usr/bin to the environment variable in the following way.

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH".
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/347466/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by changing the environment paths. The environment variables are set in ***/etc***  directory. Moving in it, there is a file named ***environment*** in which all paths are mentioned like this:

> *PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:**/usr/local/bin**:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"*

we need to add a path which is /usr/bin in the list, as here:

> *PATH="/usr/local/sbin:**/usr/bin**:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"*

after this we need to save the file and then restart the system, and then.... the job is done..

P.s. details about environment file can be found on net easily. here is a decent link:
[***/etc/environment*** file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/etc_env_file.htm)

Happy compiling ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try recompiling the binutils with --prefix= --with-sysroot

Comment: thank you dude.. but, for this one also facing same Errors.. :'(

Comment: --with-build-sysroot=SYSROOT
This will use sysroot as the system root during the build